# Better alternatives of ThreadPool C#?

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance, task, threadpool

I have a web application that has a **server running C# code**. Here's what's going on:

1. An **HTTP listener** looks for incoming requests from nodes on the network.
2. Each request is in the form of an XML document (irrelevant here, just additional information), which is parsed and sent to a method which is queued on the `ThreadPool` using `QueueUserWorkItem()`.

Now I **want to scale up** my application such that simultaneous requests from multiple nodes (to the range of 8-12k) can be processed ***without significant wait time***. My application currently hangs and refuses to process a large number of requests (to the north of 1-2k).

My current thoughts are:

- Is it just about using the `SetMaxThreads()` for the `ThreadPool`, is that the best solution? If yes, how do I decide what value to set the count to?
- Would using the Task Parallel Library help in any way? Is that a better way of interacting with `ThreadPool`?

Are there any other alternatives that I could use?

Comment: Usually you’d let the system decide thread count. And TPL won’t help here. You’ll have to find out why it hangs. What is your code doing there?

Comment: Broadly speaking, there are two possible bottlenecks. 1) Just getting those requests and 2) processing them. What if you just read and discard the XML, does it still block? Can you process your expected amount of xmls in time?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen the server sends a response to the requesting machine in the form of an xml. So it uses the data that it received (credentials etc) to build the response and then send it to the requester.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing True, the bottleneck could be building the response too, but that is secondary. There ought to be a way in which the wait time for requests can be reduced. Something better than ThreadPool.

Comment: First you'll have to determine what's causing the waiting. It's not secondary if the bottleneck is handling the requests. It's primary. Have you tested that the issue is the ThreadPool or just guessing?

Comment: How long does it take to calculate the response XML from the request XML (ignoring transmission)? If that is 10 msec, then you can handle max 100 requests/sec. To handle more, you will need more cores. If I/O-bound (database?) then maybe async/await can help somewhat.